# tsconfig for path route outside of src

Tags: node.js, typescript

My tests folder consists outside of src folder looks like this:

```
myproject/
src/
   config/
   controllers/
   types/
   schemas/
   app.ts

tests/
   data/
   routes/
     barber/
        auth/
            login.test.ts
```

When I write a test

I need to import app so I do that as this:

```
import app from '../../../../src/app';
```

is there a way to have "@"? instead of all that "../../.."?

tsconfig looks like this:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"]
},
```